# Does the sequence $x_n= n\cdot q^n$ for $0<q<1$ diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Am I correct in my understanding, that the sequence
\begin{align}
x_n= n\cdot q^n
\end{align}
for $0<q<1$ diverges? I know that for $q<1$ the sequence $a_n=q^n$ converges to 0, but since $b_n=n$ diverges I would suspect $x_n$ to diverge?

What happens for $n\to \infty$ if I have the sequence
\begin{align}
y_n= n!\cdot q^n
\end{align}
?
Thank you for tips or help!

Comment: What can you say about $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ and  $\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}$ ?

Comment: mhm okay , so for $x_n$ it would be $\frac{(n+1)\cdot q^{n+1}}{n\cdot q^n}=\frac{(n+1)\cdot q^{n}\cdot q}{n\cdot q^n}=\frac{(n+1)\cdot q}{n}=\frac{nq}{n}+\frac{q}{n}\to q$ for $n\to \infty$?

Comment: So intuitively, $x_n$ will behaves likes $q^n \to 0$ for large $n$. It should help you to find the limit and proove it rigorously. Same for $y_n$.

Comment: I think I got it, thanks!